# Knocking well pipes

Tags: plumbing

As my well pump shuts off after getting up to pressure I can here the underground pipe that goes to the well point "knocking". There is a check valve on the inlet of the pump and possibly another at the well head? Almost Sounds like the check valve slamming open/closed.  Any idea what could cause this??

Comment: Perhaps it's water hammer?

Comment: Against the check valve? If it was,  how would you stop it?

Answer (score 1):

The check valve may be sticking open, and only closing when a considerable backflow (from the pressure tank the pump just filled, towards the well) sets up after the pump shuts off (when it "slams" shut as sufficient flow unsticks the check.) Replacing the check valve should solve that issue, if that's the issue. It might also have a broken spring, and possibly a new spring could be found, though I'd bet that might be harder than finding  whole new valve.

One sticky check can do this all by itself.

IIRC you can get some non-intuitive problems from multiple checks, too.

Comment: Makes sense. If this is the case, and it's the check valve at the well point... any solutions short of digging it up? The one in the house is only a year old. To add- I get sporadic blasts of air out of the faucet at times. Could these issues be related?

Comment: You need to get to it to fix it. Without knowing more about the details of your well (which you refer to as having an evidently buried head, and then as having a well-point, which is typically connected directly to a pipe with no casing/head) it's difficult to say more. If there is a casing with a buried head, have it extended above ground and converted to use a pitless adapter, so it won't need to be dug up the next time. Leaky checks could be related to air in the system, and could also pull non-well water (possibly contaminated) into the system.

Comment: You could perhaps test by removing the check valve in the house, and see if the system holds pressure, or not?